# Java. Как обойти дерево каталогов и сохранить в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, алгоритм, рекурсия, дерево

Задача вроде простая, но споткнулся и ничего не приходит в голову.
На диске есть дерево каталогов. Например

```
\Дом и стиль жизни
\Дом и стиль жизни\Бытовая техника
\Дом и стиль жизни\Бытовая техника\Вентиляторы и обогреватели
\Дом и стиль жизни\Бытовая техника\Крупная бытовая техника
\Дом и стиль жизни\Бытовая техника\Мелкая кухонная техника
\Дом и стиль жизни\Бытовая техника\Мелкая кухонная техника\Миксеры
\Дом и стиль жизни\Ванная
\Дом и стиль жизни\Ванная\Банные полотенца
\Дом и стиль жизни\Ванная\Банные полотенца\Полотенца с капюшоном
```

И есть таблица MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `tblrazdel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_last` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

где `is_last` - указывает, последний ли каталог в своей ветке (1 или 0)

Проблема в том, что не могу корректно установить `parent_id` так, чтобы он ссылался на верный `id` родителя.

Прошу Вашей помощи.
Спасибо!

Comment: Так закиньте сначала родителей, получите их айдишники, и закидывайте детей

Comment: Да, это один из способов в лоб. Но хотелось бы именно рекурсией.

Comment: Данные позволяют залить список каталогов, а потом запросом расставить связи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные позволяют залить список каталогов, а потом запросом расставить связи.

```sql
UPDATE tblrazdel t1
JOIN ( SELECT t3.path, MAX(t2.path) parent_path
       FROM tblrazdel t3
       LEFT JOIN tblrazdel t2 ON LOCATE(t2.path, t3.path) = 1
                             AND t3.path > t2.path
       GROUP BY t3.path ) t4 USING ( path )
LEFT JOIN tblrazdel t5 ON t4.parent_path = t5.path
SET t1.parent_id = COALESCE(t5.id, 0);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a145bf453cb81c6a65d10a3c2025eb1

Comment: Вот это да! Даже не думал, что есть такой способ обработки через MySQL. Спасибо!

Comment: @SmallSani MySQL - это сервер, специально предназначенный для хранения и **обработки** данных. Поверьте - вот эта обработка из разряда самых простых. И ещё поверьте - в большинстве случаев MySQL выполнит обработку намного эффективнее Вашей программы...

Comment: Смотря на Ваш код - трудно не поверить. Буду изучать SQL более глубже. Еще раз большое спасибо!